# Is it possible to retrieve a PDF from SFTP and then put it in the Notes & Attachments?

Tags: apex

Requirement :

Fetch the **PDF file** from SFTP server, after fetching the file (based on the accountId) attach back to the Notes and Attachment related list of the account object.

The following third parties are able to process the CSV file to the corresponding object, but not the PDF files to Notes and attachments.

- Xplenty
- Skyvia
- Rssbuss

is there any way to fetch the PDF files from SFTP to Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce only supports Http and Https. You cannot do FTP calls so this cant be natively done in SF.

You have use a middleware like Mulsesoft or build something yourslef on AWS/Heroku that conevrts your HTTP calls to FTP and returns response in SF readable format.

Also, you need to make sure it does not extend HEAP of 6 Sync /12MB Async  transaction